# How to switch the "input field" between "formula mode" to "numerical mode"?

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice-calc

In the below link, I have made a simple example where A1=1, A2=2 and A3=3 and then at A5 the formula "=A1+A2+A3" is written.

What I now wonder, is there any special keyboard shortcut or icon-shortcut which would change view on the "Input line" so that the view changes from "formula mode = normal mode" to "numeric mode" (i.e. it shows values of the references... it would then show "=1+2+3" instead.)

I do not know if this function exist, and if it does not it would be super if it could be implemented. Spreadsheet is a very powerful tool, but when you are using a lot of references, it would really help if you could switch between "formula mode" and "numerical mode"...

Thanks in advance!

Link:
[Showing simple example of Libreoffice calc document](http://i.cubeupload.com/h9gFFa.png)

Comment: Have you looked at this http://superuser.com/questions/544487/how-can-i-show-values-in-the-formula-bar-instead-of-cell-references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel you can use the Evaluate Formula tool in the Formulas ribbon to step through how Excel calculates a formula. With each step (or click on <kbd>Evaluate</kbd>) the underlined part of the formula will be calculated and displayed. In the screenshot, the button has been clicked twice already, so A1 and A2 have been replaced with their values. In the next step Excel will add the two numbers. After that it will evaluate A3.

[image]

With this tool it becomes apparent that Excel does not do the calculation in one step, but uses several steps in a particular order. With more complex formulas, understanding the order of the calculation steps can be helpful for troubleshooting.

You can also edit the formula, select any part of the formula and then hit the F9 key to calculate the highlighted bit. In the screenshot, I have selected A1 and then hit F9. The cell reference has been replaced by the cell value.

[image]

When you use F9 in the formula bar, make sure to cancel out with the Escape key, otherwise the formula will actually be changed to contain the constants instead of the cell reference.

I don't know if Libre Office has similar functionality.

Comment: F9 was really useful and I suppose that this is as close you can come with current implementation of libreoffice and microsoft office. Thanks